# C# convert ReadOnlyCollection<int> to byte[] array

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, readonly-collection

Given a read only collection of ints, how do I convert it to a byte array?

```
ReadOnlyCollection<int> collection = new List<int> { 118,48,46,56,46,50 }.AsReadOnly(); //v0.8.2
```

What will an elegant way to convert 'collection' to byte[] ?

Comment: Yes, 0 to 225. I plan to use the bitConverter to convert it to string. As for the endiannass, can be both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# int byte conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641274/c-sharp-int-byte-conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `Select` method to cast each element from `int` to `byte`.
This will give you an `IEnumerable<byte>`. You can then use the `ToArray()` extension method to convert this to a `byte[]`.

```
collection.Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

If you don't want to use LINQ then you can instantiate the array and use a for loop to iterate over the collection instead, assigning each value in the array.

```
var byteArray = new byte[collection.Count];

for (var i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
    byteArray[i] = (byte)collection[i];
}
```

Comment: `int` can not be simple cast to `byte`

Comment: I think it can if the value is 0 to 255 @Backs ?

Comment: The cast is always possible, a value outside the byte range will be truncated.

Comment: Is the order guaranteed with LINQ?

Comment: @RotemVaron the order will be the same as the original collection, unless you specify `OrderBy`